# Inflate Exception in Google Map Fragment in ViewPager with TabLayout

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-tablayout, inflate-exception

I made an app in which I have displayed a Google Map with GPS location marker on my location. This map is on the 1st tab, and I also have two other tabs as shown in picture below

[image]

Now I am facing an issue i.e. when I move from tab 1 to tab 2 and then to tab 1 it works perfectly, but when I move to tab 3 and then move back to tab 1 or tab 2, the app crashes and giving the following exception in `LogCat`:

```
01-27 18:35:26.190 9414-9414/com.example.accurat.faisal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.accurat.faisal, PID: 9414
  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class fragment
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
      at com.example.accurat.faisal.MyLocation.onCreateView(MyLocation.java:62)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class fragment
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
      at com.example.accurat.faisal.MyLocation.onCreateView(MyLocation.java:62) 
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273) 
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911) 
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686) 
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619) 
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #26: Duplicate id 0x7f10010d, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3364)
      at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:192)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
      at com.example.accurat.faisal.MyLocation.onCreateView(MyLocation.java:62) 
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273) 
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911) 
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686) 
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619) 
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

It shows error at below point:

```
// inflat and return the layout
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_location, container, false);
```

Whether I choose any tab it always shows me an error on the above line, i.e. when I go to my `pictures` tab and came back to the `camera` or `my location` tab it always shows me the error on the above line.

Below is my layout

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.accurat.faisal">

<permission android:name="com.example.accurat.faisal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.accurat.faisal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"
    />


<application
    android:name=""
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_KEY"
        />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Below is my layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.accurat.faisal.MyLocation$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/section_label"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MyLocation"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label" />
```

I have searched and found many answers on them ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19952291/6854117), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8013653/6854117), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27519735/6854117)), but couldn't able to find any help on it

I am stuck to it, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: *[You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a <fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)*

Comment: @Selvin So is there no other solution else provided?

Comment: You can create SupportMapFragment programatically inside parent fragment. And no, **I will not search for you how to do this**

Comment: @faisal1208 check my answer ^_^

Comment: @Charuka sorry for late reply, i am looking into your answer, hope it will solve my problem :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Note:** You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout
>   includes a <fragment>.
>
> Nested fragments are only supported when added
>   to a fragment dynamically.

This will solve your problem,but note there can be better ones,

- Keep a static view in your maps fragment
- In `onCreateView` check the view is null , first time its gonna be null
- If there is a view (after first time load) you need to remove that,so every time when fragment gets called its like the very first time
- Then you can set your view(your my_location) to fragment so you won't get a nested fragment problem

Example:

```
 private static View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup viewGroupParent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (viewGroupParent != null)
                viewGroupParent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutWithMap, container, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // map is already there
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Find intersting answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi)

Comment: In ` parent.removeView(viewGroupParent);` where to initialize `parent`?

Comment: im glad it helped :)

Comment: this solution is absolutely right..       @thank charu bhai :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by having a MapFragment as a nested Fragment of the root ViewPager Fragment that contains the Google Map.

The cleanest and most straightforward way to fix this is by having the Fragment that goes into the ViewPager extend `SupportMapFragment` directly.

Here is a working example.

First, the Activity that contains the ViewPager Adapter which shows the Google Map in the first tab:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }
    }

    class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab One", "Tab Two", "Tab Three", };
        public Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[tabTitles.length];
        Context context;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabTitles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new MapFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new BlankFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new BlankFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // Generate title based on item position
            return tabTitles[position];
        }

        public View getTabView(int position) {
            View tab = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
            tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
            return tab;
        }

        //This populates your Fragment reference array:
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            fragments[position]  = createdFragment;
            return createdFragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == MapFragment.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION){
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) pagerAdapter.fragments[0];
            if (mapFragment != null) {
                mapFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.danielnugent.mapapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:elevation="6dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="0dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff00ff"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

custom_tab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:maxLines="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The MapFragment (from my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754169/4409409)), which directly extends SupportMapFragment, and does not need to inflate any xml layout:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //optionally, stop location updates if only current location is needed
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fragment for your map, try using a [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView). There are a lot of tutorials of how to do that.

Also change the off screen page limit of your ViewPager. You can check [this](https://spotandroid.com/2016/11/23/android-tricks-viewpager-and-offscreen-tabs/) article for more info. In this way your tabs won't be recreated when they are off the screen.

Comment: After adding `mapView` i am getting error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference`

Comment: I have done this 
`mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);`

Comment: It's not enough just to change the fragment to MapView. As I said there are lots of tutorials for that. Here is a short version of the whole idea - https://www.matt-reid.co.uk/blog_post.php?id=93 Here is longer version - https://inducesmile.com/android/android-mapview-example-tutorial/

Comment: @faisal1208 Why are you usng getChildFragmentManager(). Instead use getSupportFragmentManager(). Also add this line in your xml class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" under fragment tag. mapFrag.getMapAsync(this) only required if your class implements implements OnMapReadyCallback

Comment: I will highly appreciate it, if the down voters share their thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I respect all the answers but i found this one liner solution:
If n Is the Number of tabs then:

mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(n);

Example:
In case mentioned :

mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

View pager implements a queue so, you don't have to let it remove that fragment. onCreateView is called only once.